# Google Tink Hybrid params

Tags: java, cryptography, tink

[Google Tink](https://github.com/google/tink) supports "hybrid encryption" - a convenience method of encrypting a symmetric key with an asymmetric one, encrypting a plaintext with the symmetric key, and bundling the two ciphertexts as one message.

However, seems like it basically supports two sets of parameter combinations:

```
EciesAeadHkdfPrivateKeyManager.eciesP256HkdfHmacSha256Aes128GcmTemplate();
EciesAeadHkdfPrivateKeyManager.eciesP256HkdfHmacSha256Aes128CtrHmacSha256Template();
```

Internally, these are mapped to e.g.

```
  public static final KeyTemplate eciesP256HkdfHmacSha256Aes128GcmTemplate() {
    return createKeyTemplate(
        EllipticCurveType.NIST_P256,
        HashType.SHA256,
        EcPointFormat.UNCOMPRESSED,
        AesGcmKeyManager.aes128GcmTemplate(),
        KeyTemplate.OutputPrefixType.TINK,
        EMPTY_SALT);
  }
```

It'd seem fairly straightforward to swap e.g. `AesGcmKeyManager.aes128GcmTemplate()` for `AesGcmKeyManager.aes256GcmTemplate()`, except `createKeyTemplate` is private, and THAT uses package-private methods, and `EciesAeadHkdfPrivateKeyManager` is final, and overall it just seems like it's going out its way to prevent us from messing with those parameters.  Is there a reason for that?  Should I reconstitute my own modified version from code scrounged from the Tink source and/or just use reflection to bypass `private`, or are there hidden non-orthogonalities to trip me up and make the result insecure?

Comment: Just for clarification: you are happy with the Tink hybrid encryption but you want to change the encryption algorithm from "AES GCM 128" to "AES GCM 256" ?

Comment: @MichaelFehr Basically, yes.  The question is slightly more general - changing the parameters for hybrid encryption - but the specific parameter I'm interested ATM is AES key size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creators cite "Hard-to-misuse" as a design goal, specifically the idea of "security guarantees" for interfaces. (https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/SECURITY-USABILITY.md)

> "For example, if the underlying encryption mode requires nonces and is insecure if nonces are reused, then Tink does not allow the passing of nonces by the user."

I can see how that applies in this case, but there *is* a deprecated class (`com.google.crypto.tink.hybrid.HybridKeyTemplates`) that does what you describe. It has a public method `createEciesAeadHkdfKeyTemplate` that accepts all the internal params (https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/java_src/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/hybrid/HybridKeyTemplates.java#L127)